# How do I have to send this HTTP request?

Tags: passwords, http, arduino

I'm trying to read some information from a Website (http://www.ths-pinneberg.de/vplan/index.php?klasse=Q1c). You will need a Password. I have the Password saved on my computer but my Arduino not. My question is how the HTTP request has to look like when I want to send the Password in the same request. My current request looks like this:

```
GET /vplan/index.php?klasse=Q1c HTTP/1.1
Host: www.ths-pinneberg.de
User-Agent: arduino-ethernet
Connection: close
```

And the Server answers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 18 Aug 2017 19:06:56 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.30-0+deb8u1
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=e8d2772544a40ce8f333befb78d6429e; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

174
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>
  <title>Vertretungspl&auml;ne an der THS</title>
  <meta name="generator" content="Bluefish 2.2.9" >
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso8859-15">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css">

</head>
<body>

20e
<div id='wrap'>
<div id="header">
    <!-- Grafik f&#252;r den Header-->
    <h1>Vertretungspl&auml;ne der THS Pinneberg</h1>

</div>
<p></p><div class='login'><p>Du musst das g&uuml;ltige THS-Passwort eingeben!<br>Sie m&uuml;ssen das g&uuml;ltige THS-Passwort eingeben!</p><form action='/vplan/index.php' method='POST'><p>Passwort: <input type='password' name='password'><input type='submit' name='login' value='Anmelden'></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><input type='checkbox' name='save_password'>Dauerhaft anmelden</p></form></div>
0
```

The translation of the second last line is: "Du musst das gültige THS-Passwort eingeben!" to "You have to enter the correct password"  "Passwort" to "password"  "Anmelden" to "login" "Dauerhaft anmelden" to "remember password"

What does that request have to look like?

Comment: Use Wireshark or Fiddler to capture the request and look at it. Then just replay the request.

Comment: Send an `Authorization` header of type `Basic` with the username and password encoded in base64. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization) for details.

Answer (score 1):

just a little update I have solved my problem (thanks to GiantTree). The solution was that I programmed the Arduino to send two HTTP request, because the basic authorization didn't worked, because its just not a basic authentication. The first request goes to the login page to show it and the second request filled in the login an proceeded to the directory I wanted to see. Hope that helps others with the same problem.